# Comparação para remove_if em c++ não aceita char

Tags: c++, string, funções

Olá, estou tentando utilizar um

> remove_if

em c++ porém quando chega na parte do input eu não consigo determinar para ele detectar se a string que estou apontando possui um char. Segue meu código:

```
temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), "("), temp.end());
```

temp é uma string. queria que ele detectasse "(" mas não estou nem conseguindo compilar dessa forma. Vi algumas pessoas dizendo que é preciso criar uma função para isso, porém não sei como devo retornar tal função. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `remove_if` recebe 3 parâmetros, os iteradores de início e fim e uma função que recebe um parâmetro e retorna um `bool`. Nesse caso você pode passar a função utilizando o nome dela como se fosse uma variável.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isParenthesis (char c) {
  return c == '(';
}

int main () {
  string temp = "123(456";

  temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), isParenthesis));

  cout << temp;
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Você pode ver um exemplo também na [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if).

Comment: Consigo fazer isso para mais de um char?

Comment: Você quer comparar com mais de um `char` em `isParenthesis`? Você pode utilizar o `||` assim `return c == '(' || c == ')';`